# How to parse JSON data in scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written a webscraper in Scrapy that initially goes to [this](http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/awolnation-tickets.html) webpage, scrapes the ticket information for each ticket,and crawls to each link that the "tickets" buttons redirect to. On the tickets page, in order to get the price, a JSON [file](http://www.vividseats.com/javascript/tickets.shtml?productionId=1782609) has to be requested (which isn't much of a problem now) and the first price in the file needs to be extracted and saved into a Scrapy item loader.

I've tried to find the price object in the scrapy shell using the following statements:

```
    jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    jsonresponse["p"]
```

and

```
    jsonresponse["lp"]
```

and

```
    jsonresponse['hp']
```

but for some reason none of them are locating the price object in the file. If you look at the [tickets page](http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/awolnation-tickets/awolnation-house-of-blues-chicago-7-23-1781898.html), you can see that the lowest price is currently $28. For this specific link, I would need to get the string of $28.

I know that scrapy doesn't handle javascript and that scrapy.js can be used to integrate js into scrapy, but I'm not sure if this should even be used in this situation. In any case, what is the proper way to find this object and extract it into a variable. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
[EDIT] Here is the code so far:

```
bandname = raw_input("Enter a bandname \n")
vs_url = "http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator'
    allowed_domains = ["www.vividseats.com"]
    start_urls = [vs_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]'
def parse_json(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        #not sure what to put here yet
        return loader.load_item()

def parse_price(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        ticketLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id_list= re.findall(r"\d{2,9}", ticketsLink)
        json_id=  "".join(json_id_list)
        json_url = "www.vividseats.com/javascript/tickets.shtml?productionId=" + json_id
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

def parse(self, response):
    """
    """
   selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):

            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader

            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "name"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , './/*/a[@class = "btn btn-primary"]/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('eventDate' , './/*[@class = "productionsDate"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventCity' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventState' , './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()')
            print "Here is ticket link \n" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            ticketsURL = "concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets/" + bandname + "-" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(ticketsURL, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price, dont_filter = True)
```

Comment: Can you please show the complete code you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take [this url](http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/awolnation-tickets/awolnation-house-of-blues-chicago-7-23-1781898.html) as an example;

all ticket information corresponds to the above link is located [here](http://www.vividseats.com/javascript/tickets.shtml?productionId=1781898) and from there **you just need to map the fields of the json to html( *ticket info in the html page*).**

```
In [1]: ticket_info = jsonresponse.get('tickets')

In [2]: ticket_info
Out[2]: 
 [{u'c': u'30611',
  u'd': u'1000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'1',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB844757004',
  u'ind': u'1',
  u'l': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'n': u'Instant Download.',
  u'p': u'27.00',
  u'q': u'3',
  u'r': u'G2',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'1',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30611',
  u'd': u'1000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'1',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB891598272',
  u'ind': u'1',
  u'l': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'n': u'Instant Download.',
  u'p': u'29.00',
  u'q': u'1',
  u'r': u'G3',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'0',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30611',
  u'd': u'1000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB900500475',
  u'ind': u'0',
  u'l': u'GA MAIN FLOOR',
  u'n': u'',
  u'p': u'30.00',
  u'q': u'2',
  u'r': u'G4',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA MAIN F..',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'0',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30613',
  u'd': u'3000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB886172318',
  u'ind': u'1',
  u'l': u'GA Second Balcony - Limited View',
  u'n': u'eTicket,Obstructed/Limited View Instant Download.',
  u'p': u'37.00',
  u'q': u'1',
  u'r': u'GA',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA Second Balcony - Limited View',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'1',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30611',
  u'd': u'1000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'1',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB806449210',
  u'ind': u'1',
  u'l': u'GA MAIN FLOOR',
  u'n': u'eTicket Instant Download.',
  u'p': u'39.00',
  u'q': u'8',
  u'r': u'GA',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA MAIN F..',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'1',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30612',
  u'd': u'2000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB900500473',
  u'ind': u'1',
  u'l': u'GA First Balcony',
  u'n': u'Instant Download.',
  u'p': u'46.00',
  u'q': u'2',
  u'r': u'G3',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA First Balcony',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'0',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30611',
  u'd': u'1000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB893201517',
  u'ind': u'1',
  u'l': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'n': u'Instant Download.',
  u'p': u'50.00',
  u'q': u'6',
  u'r': u'G5',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'3',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30615',
  u'd': u'995',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'07/19/15',
  u'i': u'VB900847659',
  u'ind': u'0',
  u'l': u'GA',
  u'n': u'Tickets will be ready for delivery by 07/19/2015.',
  u'p': u'53.00',
  u'q': u'4',
  u'r': u'GA',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'0',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30615',
  u'd': u'995',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'07/19/15',
  u'i': u'VB900847710',
  u'ind': u'0',
  u'l': u'GA',
  u'n': u'Tickets will be ready for delivery by 07/19/2015.',
  u'p': u'53.00',
  u'q': u'3',
  u'r': u'GA',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'0',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30612',
  u'd': u'2000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB900500474',
  u'ind': u'1',
  u'l': u'GA First Balcony',
  u'n': u'Instant Download.',
  u'p': u'57.00',
  u'q': u'8',
  u'r': u'G2',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA First Balcony',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'3',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30611',
  u'd': u'1000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB880887546',
  u'ind': u'0',
  u'l': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'n': u'eTicket',
  u'p': u'61.00',
  u'q': u'4',
  u'r': u'GA',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'1',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30611',
  u'd': u'1000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB893198548',
  u'ind': u'1',
  u'l': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'n': u'Instant Download.',
  u'p': u'85.00',
  u'q': u'8',
  u'r': u'G4',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'3',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30611',
  u'd': u'1000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB893198623',
  u'ind': u'1',
  u'l': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'n': u'Instant Download.',
  u'p': u'94.00',
  u'q': u'2',
  u'r': u'G4',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'0',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30611',
  u'd': u'1000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'1',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB844757006',
  u'ind': u'1',
  u'l': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'n': u'Instant Download.',
  u'p': u'88.00',
  u'q': u'8',
  u'r': u'G3',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'1',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30615',
  u'd': u'995',
  u'e': u'0',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'07/19/15',
  u'i': u'VB793104621',
  u'ind': u'0',
  u'l': u'GA',
  u'n': u'Tickets will be ready for delivery by 07/19/2015.',
  u'p': u'91.00',
  u'q': u'8',
  u'r': u'GA',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'3',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30611',
  u'd': u'1000',
  u'e': u'1',
  u'f': u'1',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'',
  u'i': u'VB844757008',
  u'ind': u'1',
  u'l': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'n': u'Instant Download.',
  u'p': u'111.00',
  u'q': u'8',
  u'r': u'G4',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'1',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'0'},
 {u'c': u'30611',
  u'd': u'1000',
  u'e': u'0',
  u'f': u'0',
  u'g': u'0',
  u'h': u'07/16/15',
  u'i': u'VB791993584',
  u'ind': u'0',
  u'l': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'n': u'Zone Seating. The seller is committing to procure these tickets for you upon receipt of your order. After you place your order and your order is confirmed, we guarantee that your tickets will be within the listed zone or section listed or one comparable and that you will receive these tickets in time for the event or your money back. Orders exceeding four tickets may be split up into different rows within the requested zone or section.',
  u'p': u'170.00',
  u'q': u'6',
  u'r': u'GA',
  u'rhdn': u'0',
  u's': u'GA Main Floor',
  u'sd': u'0',
  u't': u'3',
  u'v': u'',
  u'z': u'1'}]
```

the `ticket_info` is the list of ticket-information ranging from low price to high price. Now extract only the `price-info` from the above list.
`p` is the key corresponds to the price of the ticket. Using these information it will give you something like this,

```
In [3]: price_list = [i.get('p') for i in ticket_info]

In [4]: price_list 
Out[4]: 
[u'27.00',
 u'29.00',
 u'30.00',
 u'37.00',
 u'39.00',
 u'46.00',
 u'50.00',
 u'53.00',
 u'53.00',
 u'57.00',
 u'61.00',
 u'85.00',
 u'94.00',
 u'88.00',
 u'91.00',
 u'111.00',
 u'170.00']
```

in order to make sure that you will get the lowest price you can perform `price_list.sort()` and take the first element in that.